# Image doesn't show in voyager admin panel Laravel

Tags: laravel, package, voyager

the added images are not showing in the bread of the VOYAGER ADMIN PANEL
 [image]

Anybody help ?

Answer (score 1):

1. delete storage short-link in public directory if it exists.
2. remake a new link with artisan command (php artisan storage:link)
3. confirm that the APP_URL={your domain}
4. php artisan config:cache
5. re-run the server

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried this command `php artisan storage:link`

Comment: what does this mean ?

Comment: It means the storage directory already exists on your public/ directory.
Go to your public directory and delete the storage directory then again run the command 
`php artisan storage:link`

Comment: Also, try to access your image like this http://localhost/storage/noimage.png